# The difference between "simple" and "sencilla/o"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, sinónimos

This words confuse me. When are `simple` and `sencilla` used? They both mean "simple" but are they used in certain contexts?

> Tengo un casa sencilla/simple junto al río.

I wonder if i can use both in this context?

Comment: Una casa simple junto al rio a mi me suena raro...sencilla seria lo que normalmente se usaria en ese contexto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are synonyms only when you're judging about "complexity" or "dificulty".

The most appropiate in this case would be "casa sencilla", because probably you are refering to one of these meanings:

> [sencillo, lla.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=sencillo)
>
> 3 adj. Que carece de ostentación y adornos.
>
> 4 adj. Dicho del estilo: Que carece de exornación y artificio, y expresa ingenua y naturalmente los conceptos.

However, "casa simple" also applies in some contexts. For example:

```
- ¿Tiene tu casa protección ante ataques nucleares?
- No, es una casa simple.
```

You'd say "casa simple" to specify it doesn't have complex features not expected in a "normal" house. But if your house is just "not fancy", you say "casa sencilla".